# Toyota 2006 RAV 4 - no spark

Tags: ignition, rav4

We've just replace the engine in a 2006 2.4l Rav 4.  Replacement engine uses all the (tested) sensors from the old engine.  Ran all the continuity / voltage checks for the ignition circuit and all are ok; Crank sensor and Cam sensor check ok.  However, there is a constant 4.7volt signal between all ITG terminals and ground ie ignition coil connector terminals 2 and 4.  We have re-set the ECM and no codes are showing. There is a smell of gasoline so we assume the injectors are working.
Question: What could cause the ECM to send a constant 4.7 volt signal to all ignition coils constantly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does ITG stand for?  I did a google search and couldn’t find anything.  Is that the coil pack?

Comment: Are the ignition coils connected when you read this voltage?  It may be a voltage that is used to detect if the coil is open circuit.

Comment: Thanks - IGT stands for Ignition Timing Signal (see here https://www.toyotaguru.us/engine-control-systems/igt-signal.html).  To answer your second question - no the Ignition coils are not connected.